# Why does Musescore not allow saving scores online?

Tags: sheet-music, musescore

I'm trying to save my scores at the Musescore site. In 2014 it was permitted but now you can't upload or even download scores for free any more.

Does anyone know an alternative ?

Comment: Are you sure? I think I joined MuseScore somewhere around 2016 and I used all the 5 F2P user uploads. I think I also used MuseScore uploading feature like a MIdi converter for my IGCSE exams last year (2017-18).

Comment: How do u upload scores there? I have just 5 scores to upload...

Comment: @user2535338 in the mean time musescore has changed their policy and your can upload as many scores as you want now, even without a pro account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I uploaded I thought there was a limit to the number of *free* scores you could store (5 scores from my memory.) You had to get an account after that for more storage. Obviously, they cannot offer unlimited storage for the whole world.

Free offerings like this usually change over time. Typically moving from free and open to commercial. Check the current services description. Don't rely on a free service for critical storage or access.

Comment: By "account...for more storage", I believe you mean a pro account.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, probably. I used a general wording, because services like this change constantly.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a "pro account". "Free" offers up to 10 I think. Might've changed in the meantime, don't know, since I have a "pro account" (which doesn't mean I'm a pro, it's just that they decided on a very badly named account offering).